# std::string erase to delete last letter

Tags: c++, string

I want to take some input for a game, and delete the last letter from the string after pressing backspace.  I'm not sure if I should do `text.end -1`, or `+1` to `end` to do so:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BACK))
    text.erase(text.end - 1, text.end);
```

Comment: end is a method returning iterator, so it must be `text.end() - 1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::string` actually has a [`pop_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back) method! So you can do:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BACK) && !text.empty()) { text.pop_back(); }
```

Comment: `std::string` also has an `empty()` method, so you don't have to check the `size()` for `> 0`, eg: `if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_BACK) && !text.empty()) { text.pop_back(); }`

Comment: or simply `text.size()` without not :)